# Augmented reality: Rendering function

Tags: render, augmented-reality

My question builds up on this thread: [Computer Vision / Augmented Reality: how to overlay 3D objects over vision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074434/computer-vision-augmented-reality-how-to-overlay-3d-objects-over-vision) and on its first answer. I want to build an application that projects on real time the position of a fictional 3D object into a video feed, but the first step I have to take is: How can I do this over a single image?
What I am going for at the moment is having some kind of function that given a picture, its 6D pose (position + orientation), a 3D object (on fbx, 3ds, or something easily convertable to or from others), and its own position and orientation, returns me the projection of the 3D object over the image. Once I have that, I should be able to apply it over every frame of the video feed (how will I get the 6D information of the camera is a problem I'll deal with later) 
My problem is that I am unsure where to find such a function, if it even exists. It should be offered like some kind of script or API so an external program can make use of it. Where should I look? Unity? Some kind of OpenCL functionality? So far my reading has not given me any conclusive answers, and as I am a novice in the topic, I'm sure a steep learning curve is ahead and I'd rather put my efforts on the right direction. Thank you

Comment: wrong type of questinon for stack, but this might be of interest: https://developer.vuforia.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there's an API for that.
https://developer.vuforia.com
read the GetStarted page. 
On this site, there is a "Target Manager", you'll want to upload your target images. Those will allow you to display the 3D object that you want.

On the same "page" you can have several target images. 
Example : One that display your 3D object when visible, one that makes it rotates when hided. etc ...

For the real time projection video part, I will make the assumption that, on Unity, you can have a movie texture running on a plane in background and sort your layers in a way that your 3D object is above.

Please update the topic whenever you find a way.
Bye